# rspec 3.0 belongs_to association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec3

I'm trying to test a belongs_to association using rspec 3.0 but I keep running into the error

***NoMethodError: undefined method `belong_to' for RSpec::Core***

```
  it "should belong to a user" do
ride = Ride.new
user = User.new
user.rides << ride
expect(ride).to belong_to user
```

end

I can't find anything in the documentation for rspec 3.0 to test advanced associations. Help please!

Comment: rspec doesn't have anything built in to test associations like that. Are you looking for a gem like `shoulda-matchers`? https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers

Comment: Don't think shoulda-matchers works with Rspec 3.0 just yet - I ended up using respond_to instead. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply check the association:

```
it "belongs to a user" do
  ride = Ride.new
  user = User.new
  user.rides << ride
  expect(ride.user).to be user
end
```

In this context, the `be` matcher verifies object identity. So this will pass if and only if the `user` object has the same `object_id`. In this case, that is what you want and is semantically meaningful with how it is read.

Answer (score 1):

shoulda-matchers is the gem that provides association, validation, and other matchers.

Look at this answer:
[Testing associations with rspec-rails 3.0.1 and shoulda doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24029606/testing-associations-with-rspec-rails-3-0-1-and-shoulda-doesnt-work#answer-24050319)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using

`expect(ride).to respond_to :user`

Comment: well that doesn't test that the association exists - just that the instance will respond to the method symbol `:user`.